# setState not merging but replacing

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have some state

```
  state = {
    theme: {
      background: { bgType: 'colour', value: '#449dc7' },
      primary: '#4d5a66',
      secondary: '#476480',
    },
  };
```

When I try and update a nested property such as `background` I call `setState` as follows

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  theme: { background: { bgType: 'colour', value: color.hex } },
}));
```

This however just replaces the state with

```
  theme: { background: { bgType: 'colour', value: color.hex } },
```

I lose the other properties

Comment: its because you are assigning the new value to theme, instead of merging the old values and new value. Update it like this: `theme: { ...prevState.theme, background: { bgType: 'colour', value: color.hex } },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set only background properly in theme, you need to use spread syntax with theme and not state like

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  theme: { ...prevState.theme, background: { bgType: 'colour', value: color.hex } }
}));
```

In case you want to merge the background values too, you need to spread it too like

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  theme: { ...prevState.theme, background: { 
      ...prevState.theme.background, 
      bgType: 'colour', value: color.hex 
  }}
}));
```

Comment: For a true deep merge he should spread the state.theme.background obj as well

Comment: @DannyDelott, as mentioned in the OP case, he seems to have not been merging background value and hence I decided to omit that part. But sure will add that portion in my answer too

Answer (score 0):

Spread the inner objects as well:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  theme: { 
    ...prevState.theme,
    background: { 
      ...prevState.theme.background,
      bgType: 'colour', value: color.hex
    }
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to spread the `theme` object:

```
this.setState(({ theme }) => {
  return { theme: { ...theme, background: { bgType: 'colour', value: color.hex } } };
});
```