# Does setState() in React shallow merge or completely replace the state?

Tags: reactjs

I always thought `setState()` completely replaces the old state. If we want to shallow merge, we must use spread operator.

I found *some* old posts say React does shallow merge, not completely replace. But then I tested myself, confirm that it completely replaces.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [state_M, setState_M] = React.useState({
    count: 0,
    name: 'alpha',
    id: 123
  });

  return (
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setState_M({
            name: 'beta',
            address: 'US',
          })
        }
      >
        state_M {JSON.stringify(state_M)}
      </button>
  );
}
```

Output:

```
          {
            name: 'beta',
            address: 'US',
          }
```

Is shallow merge a deprecated behavior? Where is the documentation specifies this?

- https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

  > When you call `setState()`, React merges the object you provide into the current state.
- https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#setstate-parameters

  > If you pass an object as `nextState`, it will be shallowly merged into `this.state`.
- [is setState is shallow copy or deep copy in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59878374/is-setstate-is-shallow-copy-or-deep-copy-in-react)
- [setState not merging but replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030281/setstate-not-merging-but-replacing)

Comment: `But today I just found some old posts says react does shallow merge` Those articles are talking about `this.setState` in class components. It does a shallow merge. The state setter returned by `useState` in function components is a different function, and it replaces state.

Comment: @NicholasTower I see, but that feels inconsistent. So for class component in 2023 `this.setState()` still uses shallow merge?

Comment: Yes, they are deliberately inconsistent. In class components there is just one state object and just one setState function. In function components you can create as many states as you want, with their own state setters. So needing to merge states is much less common. `So for class component in 2023 this.setState() still uses shallow merge? ` Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `this.setState` in class components. It does a shallow merge. The state setter returned by `useState` in function components is a different function, and it replaces state.

- *(see comment)*